# crontab wont work

Tags: python-3, raspbian-buster

Can someone give me a tip on how to execute a .py file in a directory/folder on the rasp pi desktop?

The .py file location is `/home/pi/Desktop/ben`

and file name is `tkKerasPredictGmail.py`

I did an edit to the crontab service with this command in console `crontab -e` and I am attempting to run this .py file everyday at 815 AM:

`15 8 * * * sudo /home/pi/Desktop/ben/tkKerasPredictGmail.py`

Would anyone have any tips to try?? Also how could I modify the day of week in crontab instruction to run the script only monday-friday (exclude weekends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add this in your Python script (on the first line):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and make it **executable** (`chmod +x`)

or adapt your cron line as follows:

```
15 8 * * * sudo /usr/bin/env python3 /home/pi/Desktop/ben/tkKerasPredictGmail.py
```

If you are using Python2 or your Python is in a different location you can check with: `which python2` or `which python3`

Regarding the cron entry you can certainly choose the days of the week (and even of the month), your entry will thus look like this:

```
15 8 * * 1-5
```

> The time and date fields are:
>
> ```
>       field          allowed values
>       -----          --------------
>       minute         0-59
>       hour           0-23
>       day of month   1-31
>       month          1-12 (or names, see below)
>       day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
> ```

Source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

Suggestion: always log the output of cron jobs to a file, this will help you with troubleshooting. See for example: [How to log cron jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4811738/6843158)

Comment: A very good tool for building CRON job lines can be found at https://crontab-generator.org/ - feed in the time details, the program details and out pops the line

Comment: You should not advice to use python2. It isn't supported anymore.